# Algorithm to arrange randomly sized rectangle images with optimally maximum spacing between them

Tags: algorithm, random, graph-algorithm, overlap

I need to disperse my images over a rectangular area such that there is optimal spacing (evenly dispersed/distributed) between each image and the sides of the rectangle - Not concentrated in any one area. Think of it as the aim is not just to fit the images on the rectangle but to maximize spacing between them.

1. Images will have a maximum width & height but can have different aspect ratios
2. Rectangle will be large enough to encompass the images
3. No-overlapping obviously
4. Images will not be tilted

Any ideas or clarifications people?

Comment: Can you define optimal?

Comment: mathematically, you can't maximize spacing as in area, just choose where to distribute it. Space = RectangleArea - imageArea. So by optimal spacing, do you mean evenly distributed?

Comment: Optimal = evenly distributed and Yes, for example if there is only 1 image that it should be placed at the center of the rectangle (equally spaced from the edges of the rectangle.

Comment: Another example: if there are 2 images then each image should be placed such that there is maximum space between the other image and the sides of the rectangle.

Comment: Try to make it as compact as possible first (you can probably modify an image sprite algorithm for this). Then put in the spacing. (eg: find all the center points of your rectangles, and enlarge those points from the middle of the container by a ratio of container size/minimal container size)

Comment: @Kicsi: Clever.  You'd want to make it compact as possible matching the ratio of the bounding rectangle, but yeah.  I like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210979/Fast-optimizing-rectangle-packing-algorithm-for-bu) is the description of an algorithm that finds an optimal envelop for image sprites. You can easily bound it to your container side. Then as per my comment:  find all the center points of your rectangles, and enlarge those points from the middle of the container by a ratio of container size/minimal container size. It may cause the images to be scattered more along one axis than the other (ie: they are scattered horizontally, but they almost touch each other vertically). If thats a problem, try the first step with smaller bounds (reduce both x and y by 10% for example).